# How do I get the selected item in MvxLIstView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

I have added Item Click in `MvxBind` property.But I am unable to send the selected item along with its `position`.Help me with this.

Here i need Item.`position` or `item` to be sent.

```java
 public ICommand ListItemSelected
 {

      get{

          return new MvxCommand<Person>(item =>{
                    _navigationService.Navigate<ThirdViewModel>(item);
          });
      }
 }
```

I am not able to send item here.I have added that item in `ThirdViewModel` constructor.

Comment: How do you set your CommandParameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

```
public IMvxCommand listItemSelected
        {
            get
            {
               return new MvxCommand<Person>((item) =>
                {
                    _navigationService.Navigate(new ThirdViewModel(item));
                });
            }
        }
```